# The absolute element change when parent fixed element add border in Chrome(77.0.3865.90)

Tags: css, position, css-position, fixed, absolute

In chrome browser, when a border is added to the parent fixed element, its absolute child element location changes, specifically by the outer border of the parent element, but not in edge and Firefox browsers.

```js
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("click",()=>{
  document.getElementById('fixed').classList.add("border");
 })
 document.getElementById('delete').addEventListener("click",()=>{
  document.getElementById('fixed').classList.remove("border");
 })
```

```css
 .fixed{
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
 }
 .absolute{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  background: yellow;
 }
 .border{
  border:8px solid green;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>TSET</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fixed" id="fixed">
 <div class="absolute" ></div>
 <button id="add">add</button>
 <button id="delete">delete</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a Chrome bug, they do not trigger the recalculation of the position

You could work around this by making sure the position is recalculated
you can also use

```
right:0.000001px;
```

if you do dot what to write the width in two separate rules. But I think this is uglier than the solution below

```js
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("click",()=>{
  document.getElementById('fixed').classList.add("border");
 })
 document.getElementById('delete').addEventListener("click",()=>{
  document.getElementById('fixed').classList.remove("border");
 })
```

```css
 .fixed{
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
 }
 .absolute{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  background: yellow;
 }
 .border{
  border:8px solid green;
 }
.fixed{
 position: fixed;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 background: red;
}
.absolute{
 position: absolute;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 background: yellow;
}
.border{
 border:8px solid green;
}
  .border .absolute{
left:calc(100% - 30px);
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>TSET</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fixed" id="fixed">
 <div class="absolute" ></div>
 <button id="add">add</button>
 <button id="delete">delete</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```